# Excel range to use the first column

Tags: c#, excel

I want to set the range of the excel column to first so I am giving it by using this line of code.

```
ExcelRange FirstcolumnRange = worksheet.Cells[rowPositionStart + 1, 1, dt.Rows.Count, 1];
```

because here row position is set to 4, I only want to use this whole column but the exception is thrown:

```
"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: Start cell Address must be less or equal to End cell address."
```

Comment: Are you sure worksheet.Cells takes 4 arguments? Though the error is something else...I suspect you are missing something, is this error really on this line?

Comment: yes it takes 3 types of arguments 1st one is single[string adress],the other type has two for a particular cell[row,col] and in last 4 arguments containing range[row,col,row,col]

Comment: To get the whole column try: `worksheet.Columns[columnNumber]`